# Cause bash statement to error if its subshell errors

Tags: bash, shell

Is there a concise, general, idiomatic bash construction that would force a statement to error when a subshell it invokes errors? For example,

```
cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel)
```

will invariably return `0` even if the `git` command errors, which makes it difficult to script something like

```
cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) && echo 'Success!'
```

Of course you can just do the following, but I was wondering if there was a better way:

```
DIR=$(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) && cd $DIR && echo 'Success!'
```

Comment: `set -e` is one way.

Answer (score 1):

It's not quite a general solution, but in that example you could do:

```
cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel || echo -@) && echo 'Success!'
```

This solution works by turns the output into something that the command won't accept if the command in the substitution fails.